# Python find string within a string using substring

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to find a the whole word within a string which contains a sub string.

For instance If replacement is a string and I will search for replace , so it will match replacement and it should return replacement.

Here is what I tried

```
>>> a = 'replacement replace  filereplace   filereplacer'
>>> re.findall(r'replace',a)

['replace', 'replace', 'replace', 'replace']
```

But what I need is:

```
['replacement', 'replace', 'filereplace', 'filereplacer']
```

Comment: Search from replace to whitespace or end of line.

Comment: You may use [`[x for x in a.split() if 'replace' in x]`](https://ideone.com/xg8QQ3) or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match with word boundaries and `\w` (which is also robust to punctuation):

```
import re

a = 'replacement replace  filereplace,   filereplacer.  notmatched'
print(re.findall(r'\b\w*replace\w*\b',a))
```

result:

```
['replacement', 'replace', 'filereplace', 'filereplacer']
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your list using your separator (space here):

```
l_s = a.split()
```

Then look for your substring in each element of the list:

```
[word for word in l_s if string_to_find in word]
```